# How to resolve "Failed to build phonopy spglib" error when "pip install asr"?

Tags: python, c++, windows, pip

My python version is 3.7, my pip version is 21.1.2, and I am on a windows 10 PC.
I am trying to install asr, but I'm getting this error:

```
Building wheel for phonopy (PEP 517) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\githome\krypton-qa\framework_v3\env37\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\githome\krypton-qa\framework_v3\env37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmpbp7x0fox'
     cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-fzaktkwv\phonopy_5860a2beb9e143eb9fb6e2b154f0305d
Complete output (100 lines):
```

Skipped a few lines

```
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for phonopy
  Building wheel for spglib (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\githome\krypton-qa\framework_v3\env37\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\githome\krypton-qa\framework_v3\env37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmp36auw2oc'
       cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-fzaktkwv\spglib_8c2bccb6bc6a4348bd9209e76933f372
  Complete output (12 lines):
  setuptools is used.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\spglib
  copying spglib\spglib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\spglib
  copying spglib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\spglib
  running build_ext
  building 'spglib._spglib' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for spglib
Failed to build phonopy spglib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for phonopy, spglib which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I have tried to download the C++ Build Tools according to the error message, but the same error messages still pops up.

Any help or insight will be appreciated!